# How to serve templates for 2 different Django apps from the same folder?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The question is pretty self explanatory.

Basically, I have 2 apps running in the same project. I want to serve all my templates from one single folder called templates, preferably placed in my project's root folder. However, Django serves templates from within the app's folders.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure `TEMPLATES` in your settings. [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#configuration)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [], # Here, add your path to folder templates
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

If your settings file is in your project's root folder. You can write `DIRS` like this :

```
 'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a line

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories
```

somewhere in your settings files near the template loaders. Comment it out if you have it.

If you dont specify TEMPLATE_LOADERS anywhere, by default django will load the app_directories loader.
In short, you want this somewhere in your settings.py:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = ['django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
# 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader'
]
```

Then configure your templates such as in the [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES)